# VNC notification not works on Ubuntu 16.04, Gnome Classic

Tags: gnome, remote-desktop, vnc, notification, gnome-classic

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and run default VNC server Vino. One difference from usual workstation - I am using Gnome classic desktop.

VNC connection works fine, though I not see any notification when somebody connects to my workstation and when it disconnects. As I see from

```
vino-preferences
```

**Show notification area icon** section says notification should be shown if anybody connects, but this not happen or I just do not know how to see notification

[image]

**I would like to get some control on external connections, be able to see if anybody connected and drop connection on my will. Please help.**

I still able to know somebody tries to access my workstation with **You must confirm each access ...** flag. On external connection attempt it brings popup, then if I confirm it is connected, though I not see when external user disconnects.